# Empty property of a string in DLang

Tags: string, d

https://dlang.org/library/std/string/to_stringz.html says that string has `empty` property.

But it does not, as the following program fails to compile:

```
import std.stdio;

string s = "";

void main() {
  writeln(s.empty);
}
```

What is wrong?

Also is this `empty` property of strings of zero length or for `null` string? I am confused.

What does `toStringz` does if called with `null` argument?

Comment: If you see a function in D, first thing you should try is looking it up with my website by going to http://dpldocs.info/empty (or /whatever function you are looking for). Quite often, it will show you the library version as the top result and then you can see which module it is imported from (so this is `import std.range.primitives;`, or `import std.range;` would also work as in this case since the primitives module is public imported over many different places);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' think `empty` is a property of `string` but it's a function of that can be applied to [ranges](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/basics/ranges). Thanks to [*uniform function call syntax*](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/gems/uniform-function-call-syntax-ufcs) (UFCS) it might look like a property, but it's not. The following compiles and prints `true` three times:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.array : empty;

string s = "";

void main()
{
    writeln(empty(s)); // normal function call syntax
    writeln(s.empty()); // UFCS
    writeln(s.empty); // UFCS - empty parenthesis can be left out
}
```

This has been explained e.g. in [Programming in D](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ranges.html):

> Merely importing the `std.array` module makes the most common container type conform to the most capable range type: slices can seamlessly be used as `RandomAccessRange` objects.
>
> The `std.array` module provides the functions `empty`, `front`, `popFront()` and other range functions for slices. As a result, slices are ready to be used with any range function.
>
> It is not necessary to import `std.array` if the `std.range` module has already been imported.